# Can i take a control of particular cluster in my GPU?

Tags: kernel, opencl, gpu

I am new to OpenCL. For example assume my GPU architecture is like this:

> Number of Multiprocessors : 14
>
> Warp size : 32

Now i want to do task parallelism. I have 14 streaming multiprocessors

1) can i run 14 different tasks concurrently??

2) if so, how to do??

3) how to mention global id, group id, local id and all..

explain clearly with example(with some thread count)

Thanks in advance..:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GPUs aren't like CPUs.  While a CPU can operate in "task parallel" mode which means they can run different code on each core.  GPUs however are "data parallel" and are SIMT (Single Instruction Multiple Threads).

This all means that you can only run one kernel at a time but that kernel will execute on all the cores and each one will operate on a slice of data concurrently.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8603471/parallelism-in-gpu-cuda-opencl) and its accepted answer has a whole lot more info that describes SIMT and has a whole lot of useful info that I wont duplicate here.

The only way you can get task parallelism on GPUs is to actually have multiple GPUs/devices.

Technically, the OpenCL API supports executing multiple kernels at once using `CL_QUEUE_OUT_OF_ORDER_EXEC_MODE_ENABLE` when you create the command queue using [clCreateCommandQueue](https://www.khronos.org/registry/cl/sdk/1.2/docs/man/xhtml/clCreateCommandQueue.html).  There is no guarantee that kernels are executed concurrently, however, in this mode, and I'd guess all the GPU OpenCL implementations would just execute each kernel one-by-one.  If you use a CPU-based OpenCL implementation this may not be the case and you might get the kernels executing concurrently (I haven't tried this myself).

Comment: Thank you for answer.. Meaningful.. Then what is the use of clEnqueueTask in out of order of execution mode.. in my perception atleast they will run concurrently with minmum time gaps, but not sequentially.. am i right? so we can do Task Parallelism on GPU also.. checkout this link (at bottom task parallel diagram).. http://www.fixstars.com/en/opencl/book/OpenCLProgrammingBook/calling-the-kernel/

Comment: @Fakruddeen if the hardware supports task parallelism then it is possible OpenCL will execute kernels concurrently, but current GPU hardware by design wont be able to do this.